# Use a yet to be defined variable as a kwarg in Python

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, keyword-argument

Here's my set up:

```
X = [0,1,2,3]
y = [10,20,30,40]

def mainfunc(X,y,**kwargs):
    for i in range(len(y)):
        c = subfunc(a=X[i],b=y[i],**kwargs)
        print c

def subfunc(a,b,c=None):
    if c is not None:
        return a*b + c
    else:
        return a*b
```

If I run `mainfunc(X=X,y=y)` or `mainfunc(X=X,y=y,c=2)` I'll get the results I expect.
But what I'm ultimately interested in, is to run `mainfunc(X=X,y=y,c=i)`, where `i` is the index of the `mainfunc` loop. 
Is that something I can do?

Comment: No. What would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, `kwargs` acts basically like a dictionary, and when you unpack it with `**kwargs` then its keys become passed variable names and the associated values are passed as-is. All of this would respect the scope.

`mainfunc(X=X, y=y, c=i)` will throw an error if you call it anywhere except inside `mainfunc` after the start of the `for` loop. Anywhere else, and it's out of scope.

I think another example that would help to understand how this works would be to call `mainfunc(X=X, y=y, a=2)`. This will produce an error

```
TypeError: subfunc() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

when the method tries to call `subfunc`, because two arguments have the same name but different values, and this cannot be resolved.

So, in summary, that's how `**kwargs` expansion works in python, and also keep scope in mind.